# Dereferencing multi-dimensional array name and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I have this multi-dimensional array:

```
char marr[][3] = {{"abc"},{"def"}};
```

Now if we encounter the expression `*marr` by definition (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) it says (and I quote)

> If the operand has type 'pointer to type', the result has type 'type'

and we have in that expression that marr decays to a pointer to his first element which in this case is a pointer to an array so we get back 'type' array of size 3 when we we have the expression *marr. So my question is why when we do (*marr) + 1 we add 1 byte only to the address instead of 3 which is the size of the array.

Excuse my ignorance I am not a very bright person I get stuck sometimes on trivial things like this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: size of "abc" is 4, char a[4] = "abc";// { 'a','b','c','\0' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds one because the type is char (1 byte). Just like:

```
char *p = 0x00;
++p; /* is now 0x01 */
```

When you dereference a `char [][]` it will be used as `char *` in an expression.

To add 3, you need to do the arithmetic first and then dereference:

```
*(marr+1)
```

You were doing:

```
(*marr)+1
```

which dereferences first.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer I understand everything you've said here except when you say "When you dereference a char [][] it will be used as char * in an expression" Why is that ? doesn't the name of the array decay to a pointer to its first element which in this case is a pointer to an array of size 3 so the type is char array of size 3 ?

Comment: @wel yep, a char [][] wil decay into char (*)[], right? (pointer to array, just like you said) so when you dereference it, you'll have a char array. But this one, when used in an expression, decays into a pointer to its first element (again), so you end up with char *. And incrementing a pointer to a char adds 1 . If instead you do *(marr+1), first you have marr decaying into a pointer to array of size 3, and incrementing it increments it's type size (which is array of size 3 of char) so you get a +3 increment. Then you dereference this one. It's kind of hard, yes…

Comment: Thanks my friend I've got it now. I sort of figure this at first but was very unsure thanks for your patience and time. Your answer is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Glad to help @wel . These things can be really confusing! Best wishes and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

The reason why incrementing `(*marr)` moves forward 1 byte is because `*marr` refers to a `char[3]`, `{"abc"}`. If you don't already know:

```
*marr == marr[0] == &marr[0][0]
(*marr) + 1 == &marr[0][1]
```

If you had just `char single_array[3] = {"abc"};`, how far would you expect `single_array + 1` to move forward in memory? 1 byte right, not 3, since the type of this array is `char` and `sizeof(char)` is 1.

If you did `*(marr + 1)`, then you would be referring to `marr[1]`, which you can then expect to be 3 bytes away. `marr + 1` is of type `char[][3]`, the increment size is `sizeof(char[3])`.

The key difference about the two examples above is that:

- The first is dereferenced to a `char[3]`, and then incremented, therefore the increment size is `sizeof(char`).
- The second is incrementing a `char[][3]`, therefore the increment size is `sizeof(char[3])`, and then dereferencing.

Comment: Thank you sir your answer is also very much appreciated and helpful. You guys are great.